# Sort all rows horizontally by reference to columns in a particular row

Tags: text-processing, sort

I need to sort horizontally, not vertically, and `sort` seems to be designed for vertical operation. q E.g., I have three rows as follows:

```
banana/orange/apple/mango
potato/tomato/onion/garlic
chair/table/carpet/window
```

All rows have the same number of columns, separated by a `/`. I want the columns to be re-arranged according to alphabetical order in row 1. So it will become:

```
apple/banana/mango/orange
onion/potato/garlic/tomato
carpet/chair/window/table
```

This might be better visualized as shown below:

[image: text in colored columns]

i.e., like sort-by-column in a spreadsheet.

Comment: You don't happen to be on a BSD system (OS X, for example)? If so, do you have the the `rs` utility?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `awk`, you may dictate the order in which arrays are traversed by setting `sorted_in` within `PROCINFO`. In this instance, set it to `@val_str_asc` to force arrays to be traversed in ascending order of values.

Next split the first line into an array `a` 
Finally, for each line, traverse the array and print fields corresponding to the keys as they are retrieved.

```
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"};
   FNR == 1{n = split($0, a)};
   {x=0; for (k in a) printf "%s%s", $k, ++x == n? "\n": FS}' file

apple/banana/mango/orange
onion/potato/garlic/tomato
carpet/chair/window/table
```

Or, with `python`

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open('file') as f:
    keys = next(f).rstrip('\n').split('/')
    print(*sorted(keys), sep='/')
    for line in f:
            g = (m for l, m in sorted(zip(keys, line.rstrip('\n').split('/'))))
            print(*g, sep='/')

apple/banana/mango/orange
onion/potato/garlic/tomato
carpet/chair/window/table
```

Comment: So I tried:   

gawk -F'/' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"};  
   FNR == 1{n = split($0, a)};  
   {x=0; for (k in a) printf "%s%s", $k, ++x == n? "\n": FS}' file  ...and I got error msg "'FNR' is not recognised as an internal or external command"', then I tried removing the two line breaks in the command and got an output file that just had "sssssssssssss" in it, and then tried removing both the two line breaks and the two semi-colons (just for the hell of it because I'm flying blind) and got the same output: "sssssssssssssss".

Comment: @Simonmdr, what version of `gawk` do you have? Please provide output from `gawk --version`

Comment: GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.3, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic approach would be

- create a list of indices, sorted in the order of the first row - for example as described here: [How to return a sorted list's index in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124792/how-to-return-a-sorted-lists-index-in-perl)
- slice the rows using the list

So

```
perl -F'/' -alne '
   our @inds = sort { $F[$a] cmp $F[$b] } 0..$#F if $. == 1; 
   print join "/", @F[@inds]
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Using [GNU `datamash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash), *transpose*, sort, and *transpose* again:

   ```
   datamash -t '/' transpose < file | datamash -t '/' -s -g1 transpose
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   apple/banana/mango/orange
   onion/potato/garlic/tomato
   carpet/chair/window/table
   ```
2. Various *software tools*:

   ```
   join -a 1 -t / -o $( head -n 1 file | \
                        tr / '\n' | \ 
                        nl  -n ln | \
                        sort  -k2 | \
                        cut   -f1 | \
                        sed -n 's/^/1./;H;1h;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/ //gp}' ) \
         file /dev/null
   ```

   How that works: `join` can reorder columns, via parameters passed to its `-o` option.  So (using no variables and no arrays) the trick is to generate those parameters:

   1. `head` gets the first line,
   2. `tr` converts that to several lines,
   3. which `nl` numbers,
   4. `sort` by the 2nd column, (i.e. *apple*, etc.),
   5. and `cut` the reordered list of numbers in column #1,
   6. `sed` converts the numbers to a format that `join` likes.

Comment: This answer is wrong, because you misread/misunderstood the question. (Note that the question shows the desired output, and your output does not match it.) Your comment on the question seems to reflect the same misunderstanding.

Comment: @G-Man, you're right -- thanks for the correction *and* the OP color coding.  (I now recall having having mistook the OP's needed output for a typo.)  In light of which, I've made a revised and somewhat different answer.

Answer (score 2):

On BSD with [the `rs` utility](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/rs.1):

```
$ rs -T -c'/' <data.in | sort | rs -T -C'/' >data.out
```

- `-T` transposes
- `-c'/'` sets the input column delimiter
- `-C'/'` sets the output column delimiter

Looking at it:

```
$ cat data.in
banana/orange/apple/mango
potato/tomato/onion/garlic
chair/table/carpet/window

$ cat data.out
apple/banana/mango/orange/
onion/potato/garlic/tomato/
carpet/chair/window/table/
```

Removing the superfluous `/` at the end:

```
$ sed 's#/$##' data.out
apple/banana/mango/orange
onion/potato/garlic/tomato
carpet/chair/window/table
```